# Html Table width with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have data coming in and I parse it into a table on a webpage. There are 3 cells side by side to each other. (Cell 0,0 : Cell 0,1 : Cell 0,2)

I'm trying to making it so that the cells are evenly split across the div making it so the first cell's text is aligned left, middle cell is aligned center and last cell is aligned right.

I've tried the following for css

```css
td {
   width: calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<table border=1 style="border: 1px red dashed; width: 250px;">
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td>second with wider contents</td>
<td>third</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border=1 style="border: 1px blue dashed; width: 250px;">
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td>second</td>
<td>third with wider contents</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't give me the output I'm looking for. What I'm trying to accomplish is I have multiple tables on one page and want the cells to be aligned all the way down

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)
Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: `width: calc(100%/3);` BTW why do you need `calc`? It's a constant, the result of the operation is 33%, so why don't you use `width: 33%` instead?

Comment: In addition to a snippet (and/or fiddle), can you expand on what you mean by "doesn't give me the output I'm looking for"? I.e., can you show us what you're doing and explain specifically how the result differs from the desired/expected result?

Comment: When you use more than one table like that, they won't align equally unless you give each cell a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting your table to the full width of the div that it's nested in?

For example:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


td {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Just made this quick, I think this is what you're looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/nsxLfv00/

Comment: This was the answer, my table was not set to the full size of the div

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the alignment of the content in the three cells use the [n-th child css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
td:nth-child(1){
   text-align: left;
}
```

and accordingly for the middle and the right column.

Answer (score -1):

While it's possible in pure CSS, I would advice you Bootstrap, Flexbox or any grid framework to achieve that easily.
In BS it would be something like :

```
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Your first cell content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      second
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      third
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

You may, of course, insert your table structure if you need to.

Comment: Using Bootstrap for this problem is overkill. OP's given no indication that they're using any CSS framework. Plus, OP might have to learn how to use Bootstrap and could spend days on the problem instead of minutes.

Comment: @amphetamachine : Even if you're right on this point, it wasn't mentioned whether it was a small or big project. It happens very often that freelance back end developers don't know these frameworks when they switch to front end projects. And seriously, learning BS is not like learning node.js, once you stick to the documentation...